# Запись каждого элемента массива в отдельный файл

Tags: python-3.x, массивы

Мне нужно, чтобы 1й элемент массива записывался в 1й файл в папке, 2й элемент в 2й файл и т.д. Этот код записывает только 1й элемент во все созданные файлы.

```
mypath = "C:/Users/dexp/Desktop/songs beatstar/songs/"
with open("C:/Users/dexp/Desktop/songs beatstar/name_songs.txt") as file_in:
    lines = []
    for line in file_in:
        lines.append(line.rstrip())
with open("C:/Users/dexp/Desktop/songs beatstar/score_songs.txt") as file_in1:
    scores = []
    for line1 in file_in1:
        scores.append(line1.rstrip())
print(lines)
print(scores)
for file in lines:
    FileFullPath = os.path.join(mypath, file)
    with open(FileFullPath, 'w') as f:
        f.write(scores[0])
```

Comment: ну вы же сказали записывать `scores[0]` вот он его и пишет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Откорректированы 3 строки с комментариями - проверьте. Полностью согласен с комментарием @n1tr0xs, что не менялся элемент массива.

```
mypath = "C:/Users/dexp/Desktop/songs beatstar/songs/"
with open("C:/Users/dexp/Desktop/songs beatstar/name_songs.txt") as file_in:
    lines = []
    for line in file_in:
        lines.append(line.rstrip())
with open("C:/Users/dexp/Desktop/songs beatstar/score_songs.txt") as file_in1:
    scores = []
    for line1 in file_in1:
        scores.append(line1.rstrip())
print(lines)
print(scores)
# Вводим счетчик
i = 0
for file in lines:
    FileFullPath = os.path.join(mypath, file)
    with open(FileFullPath, 'w') as f:
        # модифицируем номер  
        f.write(scores[i])
    # Увеличиваем счетчик
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы не меняете номер элемента, который записываете. Есть несколько вариантов как это исправить ([вариант Сергея](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1430329/368899) повторять, думаю не стоит):

#1 - `list.pop()` (не рекомендую использовать)

```
for file in lines:
    FileFullPath = os.path.join(mypath, file)
    with open(FileFullPath, 'w') as f:
        f.write(scores[0])
    scores.pop(0)
```

#2 `range(len(list))`

```
for i in range(len(lines)):
    FileFullPath = os.path.join(mypath, lines[i])
    with open(FileFullPath, 'w') as f:
        f.write(scores[i])
```

#3 - `zip(list, list)`

```
for file, score in zip(lines, scores):
    FileFullPath = os.path.join(mypath, file)
    with open(FileFullPath, 'w') as f:
        f.write(score)
```

#4 - `enumerate(list)`. Спасибо Эдуард Измалков за [идею](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1430319/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB/1430347?noredirect=1#comment2549998_1430347)

```
for i, file in enumerate(lines):
    FileFullPath = os.path.join(mypath, file)
    with open(FileFullPath, 'w') as f:
        f.write(scores[i])
```

2. Если у вас есть переменная путей к файлам, то лучше используйте её, а не "хардкодьте" значения:

```
mypath = "C:/Users/dexp/Desktop/songs beatstar/songs/"
with open(os.path.join(mypath, 'name_songs.txt'))
with open(os.path.join(mypath, 'score_songs.txt'))
```

3. Читать файлы лучше так (код короче, при этом ясность кода не теряется):

```
with open(os.path.join(mypath, 'name_songs.txt')) as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
with open(os.path.join(mypath, 'score_songs.txt')) as f:
    scores = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
```

Есть еще такой вариант, но он может оказаться трудным для восприятия:

```
with open(os.path.join(mypath, 'name_songs.txt')) as f:
    lines = list(map(str.rstrip, f))
with open(os.path.join(mypath, 'score_songs.txt')) as f:
    scores = list(map(str.rstrip, f))
```

---

На выходе получаем:

```
mypath = "C:/Users/dexp/Desktop/songs beatstar/songs/"

with open(os.path.join(mypath, 'name_songs.txt')) as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
with open(os.path.join(mypath, 'score_songs.txt')) as f:
    scores = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

print(lines)
print(scores)

for file, score in zip(lines, scores):
    FileFullPath = os.path.join(mypath, file)
    with open(FileFullPath, 'w') as f:
        f.write(score)
```

Comment: варианта с `enumerate` для полноты не хватает

Comment: @ЭдуардИзмалков добавил. спасибо за идею